# Stop authentication pop up on allowed directory in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi I am new here so little bit hesitating in asking question as i don't know the rules, But i will give a try.

I have successfully password protected a website using .htaccess and .htpasswd,

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/dir1" dir1_uri
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/dir2" dir2_uri
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=dir1_uri
Allow from env=dir2_uri
Satisfy any
```

As you can see i am allowing access to the dir1 and dir2.

Problem is that when i access the dir1 or dir2 through browser, the Authentication window pop up, this should not happen. Though it open the site when I cancel the pop up and can access the website without any problem. But it always pop up whenever i visit them. I don't know why this is happening.

Please help me.

Comment: More than 7 hours, But still no answer. Please I request experts to give me a solution for this

Comment: I don't fully understand.. you want password protection but without asking for a password? Its the normal behaviour of the browser to popup login form, because you `require valid-user`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have password protected whole website and i want to exclude password protection for two directory, I successfully implemented that with above code, but it show pop up whenever i visit those directory, though the pop up can be easily bypass by clicking cancel button and i can visit the site. Hope you understand.

Comment: If you don't want password protection, dude, just don't use it and remove your `.htaccess` file?!

Comment: I want password protection but want to allow those two directory to be publicly accessible through browser

Comment: Ok now I understand. Don't make these two directories subdirectories of the password protected folder then. It's the best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I able to resolve it and it was due to my own mistake. 
By debugging for continuous 6-7 hours I found that the style sheet containing **background-url** property referencing to images which are in the restrictive directory or not existing are causing to pop up authentication pop up. I fixed them and it is now working.